# How to add a reveal animation on scroll with the element (not the whole page)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**My website example:** [My website example](http://khoanguyen.dev/)

Hello, I'm trying to figure out how to add a reveal animation on scroll with the element (not the whole page). Because I set the `root background image` to `100vh` and only use an element (overflow) to scroll it vertically so that I'm not scrolling a whole page, just the one-page component. For example, this is my App.js example code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Header, Page, Footer} from "./Hooks"
import './style.css'
function App(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>     -> this one is a fixed component.
      <Page/>       -> this one can scroll vertically.
      <Footer/>     -> this one is a fixed component.
    </div>
 );
};
```

And this is the style.css code:

```
.App{
   background-image: './macos';
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   overflowY: auto;
}
```

Because of this setup, I cannot use `window.scrollTo(0,0)` function for scrolling to the top. And I'm going to create the reveal animation but don't know how to make it work. I watched a video about an `onScroll` event but it can't work on my website because of the `Page` component, because the website isn't scrolled, only the `main page component`, so `window.ScrollY` or `window.ScrollX` is always set to zero `(0,0)` (checked by `console.log()`).

I don't know how to fix this or use any kind of method. It's hard to re-create the root page UI so I don't want to have a mess with it. Thank you for all of your contributions. Anyone answers will all receive my upvote.

Comment: Of course `window.scrollY` & x are 0 if you're not scrolling the window. You can use a ref to access your page *element* and then use `element.scrollTop` and `element.scrollLeft` to access the scroll values. Note that it's not recommended to use non body tags as the main scrolling since it causes weird behavior on some devices especially IOS devices.

Comment: https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm testing it out

Comment: @Undo I tested it out but received an error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')`. This is my code:

`const profileCardRef = useRef(null);
  const scroll = () =>{
    profileCardRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }`


Thank you

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn You need to validate that ref.current is not undefined which it can be on initial render. Also if you need help with unrelated things to this question, post a new question instead.